# Can you make VS2010 Watch windows show whitespace in strings?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, watch

I've just spent an hour fixing a bug caused by me believing what the Watch window showed me. Why doesn't it indicate carriage returns in strings?

Is there an option to enable this?